# Оимпиадная задачка

Tags: алгоритм

во входном файле в первой строке число N (1 <= N <= 100000)
во второй строке N чисел от 0 до миллиона

нужно посчитать количество таких пар чисел что одно число последовательности больше другого и стоит до него в строке

Простой метод записи чисел в массив и перебора всех вариантов не подходит
Сама программа мне нужна , просто может подкинете идейку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой перебор даст вам квадратичную сложность. Но если бы для каждого числа, мы могли:

1. Получать порядквый номер числа во входной последовательности за O(1).
2. Получать список всех чисел, больше данного за O(N*logN)
3. Получать список всех чисел, с порядковым номером во входной последовательности больше данного O(N).

То смогли бы свести сложность, полагаю, к квадратично-логарифмической.

Пункты 2 и 3 можно объединить: получать список всех чисел, которые одновременно и больше данного числа, и имееют больший порядковый номер.

См. в сторону хэштаблиц для п.1 и в сторону сбалансированных деревьев поиска для пункта 2 или для объединеных пунктов 2 и 3.

Answer (score 2):

Мое имхо (Могу ошибаться, нужно сравнение с брутфорсом по ответам):

Пишете сортировку слиянием (по убыванию), в процедуре слияния считаете сколько раз "брали из первого массива, пока в начале второго массива было число меньше" (Прибавлять нужно оставшуюся длину второго массива. Он отсортированный, в нем все элементы меньше). В коде должно выглядеть примерно так:

```
<cout, array> merge(<count1, array1>, <count2, array2>) {

    while (i < array1.len && j < array2.len)
    if (array1[i] > array2[j]) {
         arrayOut.add(array1[i++]);
         countOut += array2.len - j; // считаем сколько таких пар между двумя массивами
    } else {
         arrayOut.add(array2[о++]);
    }
    // тут еще должна быть обработка остатков (с увеличением countOut в случае array1)
    countOut += count1 + count2; // прибавляем пары посчитанные внутри массивов
    return <countOut, arrayOut>
}
```

Асимптотику получаем O(nlogn) как и у самой сортировки слиянием.

Comment: Отличная идея! Должно сработать.